# Hybris for B2B - Can pricing be hidden for non-registered customers?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We are looking to implement Hybris and one important feature we are looking for is to hide pricing for non-registered customers. We do want to allow them browse the catalog but we don't want them to see any pricing information. Is this a standard feature on Hybris or do we need to have it custom coded?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to hide in only jsp(storefront) you can put price tag under security tag.

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP">
</sec:authorize>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one way to do this.

1. Log into HMC and click on the Price Settings - Prices - Customer Price Lists tree node. Create a Customer Price List.
2. Create new user group and map the registered users to belong this user group. In Customer Prices tab of the user group, Choose Customer Prices group for registered users you just created.
3. Go to Catalog-> Products and the Prices tab. Create two Price Rows, one for registered Customer Price List containing product price and the other for non-registered Customer Price List containing no product price. You don't need to create a Customer Product List for non-registered users. Just keep it blank.
4. Make sure you sync the catalog to reflect in online version.
5. If you log in with the registered user and go to product detail page you could see the price and for non-registered user, it will show no price.

PS: I have not done it myself, so I'm not 100% sure if it'll work. If it does, do let me know.